# Subscribing to an Azure Service Bus Topic with Spring Boot and AMQP

Tags: java, spring, azure, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Service bus topic set up called "state-changed" and it has a subscription called "reverb".  I'm trying to set up a method with `@JmsListener` to subscribe to the topic but am getting an error:

```
2017-03-22 18:34:41.049  WARN 23356 --- [enerContainer-6] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'state-changed' - trying to recover. Cause: The messaging entity 'sb://[MySERVICEBUS].servicebus.windows.net/state-changed' could not be found. TrackingId:d2b442f79e0f44bdb449861ea57155ce_G44, SystemTracker:gateway6, Timestamp:3/22/2017 6:34:37 PM

javax.jms.JMSException: The messaging entity 'sb://[MySERVICEBUS].servicebus.windows.net/state-changed' could not be found. TrackingId:d2b442f79e0f44bdb449861ea57155ce_G44, SystemTracker:gateway6, Timestamp:3/22/2017 6:34:37 PM
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.TopicSubscriberImpl.createClientReceiver(TopicSubscriberImpl.java:111) ~[qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.32.jar:0.32]
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageConsumerImpl.<init>(MessageConsumerImpl.java:129) ~[qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.32.jar:0.32]
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.TopicSubscriberImpl.<init>(TopicSubscriberImpl.java:46) ~[qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.32.jar:0.32]
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(SessionImpl.java:544) ~[qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.32.jar:0.32]
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(SessionImpl.java:59) ~[qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.32.jar:0.32]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.createConsumer(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:870) ~[spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.createListenerConsumer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:215) ~[spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) ~[spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1165) ~[spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) ~[spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) ~[spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

I have been using this blog post to try and get everything up and running: http://ramblingstechnical.blogspot.co.uk/p/using-azure-service-bus-with-spring-jms.html

I can add messages to the topic with `JmsTemplate` and read messages from it using the plain old Java JMS libraries outlined in the Azure docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp so I know my topic does work and is accessable, it just seems to be when I configure it with Spring that I'm doing something wrong.

My configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfiguration
{

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory topicJmsListenerContainerFactory() throws NamingException
    {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory returnValue = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        Context context = context();
        ConnectionFactory cf = connectionFactory(context);

        returnValue.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        returnValue.setSubscriptionDurable(Boolean.TRUE);
        return returnValue;
    }

    private Context context() throws NamingException
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "src/main/resources/servicebus.properties");
        Context context = new InitialContext(env);
        return context;
    }



    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     * @throws NamingException
     */
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(Context context) throws NamingException
    {
        ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("SBCF");
        return cf;
    }

}
```

servicebus.properties (with username and password etc redacted):

```
# servicebus.properties - sample JNDI configuration

# Register a ConnectionFactory in JNDI using the form:
# connectionfactory.[jndi_name] = [ConnectionURL]
connectionfactory.SBCF=amqps://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[MYSERVICEBUS]

# Register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndi_name] = [physical_name]
# topic.[jndi_name] = [physical_name]
queue.workflow = workflow
topic.state-changed = stage-changed
```

And finally my listener class:

```
@Component
public class TestListener
{
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingWorkflowEventHandler.class);

    @JmsListener(destination = "state-changed", containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory", subscription = "reverb")
    public void onMessage(String message)
    {
        logger.info("Received message from topic: {}", message);
    }
}
```

If anyone has ever managed to get this working I'd be grateful for some pointers.

Comment: What issue did you get? According to your configuration code, the `servicebus.properties` file in the code `env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "src/main/resources/servicebus.properties");` seems not to be loaded in running. Please check and change it to a relative path under `classes` root path.

Comment: The same configuration is used by other components and they seem to be working ok. I can send messages to the topic using that config, it's just my listeners that don't work.

Answer (score 5):

Your error message indicates the name of your destination is not found (message entity not found). 
Note that you need to tell Azure your Subscription name in a specific way like this:

```
<TopicName>/Subscriptions/<SubscriptionName>
```

In your case:

```
state-changed/Subscriptions/reverb
```

Hope that helps

Cheers
        Seb

Comment: Works for me after creating a subscription for my topic in Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot you can use prepared Azure ServiceBus JMS Spring Boot Starter where it works out of box.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

See a tutorial page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus

Answer (score -3):

Create or change a Trustrore:

As we want to establish a secured amqps connection to the Service Bus, we need to have all required SSL certificates stored in a truststore. As it seems that none of the existing ones contains the required certificates I - for transparency - created a new one like this:

Acquire the needed certificates by visiting `https://<URL-Of-Your-Servicebus>`, e.g. `https://XXXXX.servicebus.cloudapi.de` in a browser. Then click on the "lock" in the URL (or whatever your browser shows for a secure connection) and open the certificate from there.

Save the current certificate:

[[image: Certificate provide]]

When asked for the format to export, choose "DER binary" and save it as a ".cer" file, e.g. "1.cer"

Most likely you can see that your certificate is based on a certificate chain, which means it depends on other certificates. For each of those click "show certificate":

[[image: Certificate provide]]

And save that one in the same way as the one before. Repeat until you reach the root-certificate. In this example you will end up with three *.cer files. For further reference I will call them 1.cer, 2.cer and 3.cer

You should now create a new Truststore file for those certificates

```
/opt/webMethods9/jvm/jvm/bin/keytool -import -file
/opt/webMethods9/IntegrationServer/instances/default/packages/DEV_fse/resources/1.cer -keystore azureTruststore.jks -alias "D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 2009"

/opt/webMethods9/jvm/jvm/bin/keytool -import -file 
/opt/webMethods9/IntegrationServer/instances/default/packages/DEV_fse/resources/2.cer -keystore azureTruststore.jks -alias "D-TRUST SSL Class 3 CA 1 2009"

/opt/webMethods9/jvm/jvm/bin/keytool -import -file 
/opt/webMethods9/IntegrationServer/instances/default/packages/DEV_fse/resources/3.cer -keystore azureTruststore.jks -alias "servicebus.cloudapi.de"
```

You will be asked to set the password for this newly created truststore the first time. Now move the truststore to `/opt/webMethods9/IntegrationServer/config/certs/trusted` (for later reference). You might add it to IS as a truststore (by using the admin-UI "Security > Keystore " and "Create Truststore Alias"), but there is no technical need to do it, as in our case the IS is not using the truststore - it's only used by QPID.

Create a properties file for JNDI You need to create a `servicebus.properties` file to act as the data source for a pseudo JNDI Server. You can technically place that file wherever you want, but I would recommend putting it in the "resources" folder of the "XXXXXXConnection" package. This should be the content of that file:

```
# servicebus.properties - sample JNDI configuration
# Register a ConnectionFactory in JNDI using the form:
# connectionfactory.[jndi_name] = [ConnectionURL]
connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://XXXXXX.servicebus.cloudapi.de?jms.username=xxxxx&jms.password=xxxxxxx&amqp.idleTimeout=120000&jms.receiveLocalOnly=true&transport.trustStoreLocation=/opt/webMethods9/IntegrationServer/config/certs/trusted/azureTruststore.jks
# Register some queues in JNDI using the form 
# queue.[jndi_name] = [physical_name] 
# topic.[jndi_name] = [physical_name]
queue.QUEUE = myqueue
​
```

Some Explanations:​

1. `SBCF` will be the JNDI-Lookup name for the connection factory. This name is later needed in your JMS-Connection
2. `xxxxxx.servicebus.cloudapi.de` is the URL to your Service Bus
3. `jms.username` will be provided by your friendly Azure administrator
4. `jms.password` will be provided by your friendly Azure administrator. But be aware that you will need to URL-Encode what you will get from the admin before you can use it in this URL. This can for example be done by calling the IS Service `pub.string:URLEncode` manually in Designer.​​
5. `amqp.idleTimeout` needs to be set to 120000 (or higher) because of otherwise you cannot connect to SB
6. `jms.receiveLocalOnly` needs to be set to `true` because of otherwise you cannot connect to SB
7. `transport.trustStoreLocation` needs to point the truststore that contains all SSL Certificates that are required to create a secured (AMQPS) connection to SB
8. `queue.QUEUE`: QUEUE is the JNDI-Lookup name you will use later in your JMS-Client to send messages or in your JMS-Trigger to receive them. You should set to a something more meaningful probably. The value of this ("myqueue" in the example) is the name of the queue on the SB and has to be provided by your Azure Admin.

[[image: JNDI context factory class]]

The only two important values are:

1. "Initial Context Factory": `org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory`
2. "Provider URL": Must point to your created servicebus.properties, e.g.  `file:/opt/webMethods9/IntegrationServer/instances/default/packages/XXXXXXConnection/resources/servicebus.properties`